# Caching implementation details in wso2 esb

Tags: caching, wso2, wso2-esb

Hi I have a few questions on caching in wso2 esb.
How is caching implemented in wso2-esb?
Where is the cached data stored in RAM or in the disk?
What is the maximum size of data that can be cached by wso2 esb cache mediator?
How would we perform cache synchronization if db is updated?

Thanks

Comment: You can choose whether the data is stored in RAM or on the disk. The size of RAM/disk limits the maximum size of data that can be cached. Another limitation is int size. https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Cache+Mediator

Comment: @Maria Thanks for the information.Can you shed some light on cache synchronization and cache invalidation in wso2esb